# Running OVF on VMware Player

Tags: vmware-player

Can someone point me to documentation on running an OVF with VMware Player 3.0 (Linux)? Whenever I try running a VA from an OVF, I get a syntax error:

```
Error opening virtual machine /hafh/vmware/Filetransfer_ovf/Filetransfer.ovf: File "/hafh/vmware/Filetransfer_ovf/Filetransfer.ovf" line 1: Syntax error.
```

There is nothing in the VMware logs, because the VA never gets far enough to run. The same OVF runs on ESXi and VMware Server with no trouble.

The above error code is from a VA downloaded from the internet. I run into the same problem with my own VAs. In this case I have the vmx and that runs fine.

Suggestions? Am I on crack, does Player even run OVFs (I can't seem to find confirmation of this one way or another)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked the same question on the [VMware Community Forum](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/desktop/player?view=discussions) and got the answer. Turns out that because OVF is not a runtime format, it needs to be converted back to VMX format for Player to be able to run it. I guess ESXi and VMware server can do this themselves on loading the OVF. See details in the [forum](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1436387#1436387).